# Snap RAID and LVM

Tags: filesystems, lvm, raid

I have multiple physical disks of different sizes that I wish to create one large pool of storage space on.   The purpose of this large pool of space is to store a large encrypted file which is too large to be put on any single disk.

The problem with Snap RAID is that I can't have one file that spans multiple drives.

If I I create a large logical volume for Snap RAID then I run into the problem that  I have no disks large enough to hold the parity for the single large logical volume.  However I am not sure how LVM will handle it if I use the data partitions created by Snap raid as isn't LVM handled at a lower level?

How can I combine Snap RAID and LVM so that I can have one continuous pool of storage that can has parity calculated for each physical drive?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, isn't "_Snap RAID above LVM_" the same as "_LVM below Snap RAID_"?

Comment: I described it poorly.  I will try rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me say straight up that I'm not familiar with [Snap RAID](https://www.snapraid.it/).

If you want to involve LVM, you need to know that it allows you to coalesce different physical volumes (PV) to create a single volume group (VG).

So if Snap RAID lets you create multiple protected spaces you can put a PV on each and then amalgamate them into the one VG that can contain a Logical Volume (LV) with your filesystem and your large file.

Comment: I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, because all disks on Snap RAID need to have the same file system that I could not combine disks disks without a file system.  From my basic knowledge of LVM you can't use a disk as part of a VG if it already has a file system.  Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. A disk or partition must be given over to LVM  Once you've done so you can carve out LVs on which you place a filesystem.